# Problems with RootLocusPlot

Tags: plotting, control-systems

I am having some trouble to understand how the `RootLocusPlot` works (options, drawing and etc.)

Here is an example

```
RootLocusPlot[
 TransferFunctionModel[-((k(s-5/2)(s-2)))/((s-4)(s-1)),s], {k, 0, 10},
 PlotRange-> {{-10, 15}, {-5, 5}}, AxesOrigin->{0, 0}
]
```

[image]

I have no problem to draw the RL by hand despite the negative gain (note that there is a problem with $k=1$ when closing the loop).   When I use *Mathematica* to do the same thing, the output does not seem right even when I increase/decrease the range of `k`, the number of `PlotPoints`, the scale and etc.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I can explain what is happening with `RootLocusPlot`, and it will also be useful for you to show the result you obtained by hand and why the result of `RLPlot` does not seem right compared to that.

(My explanation is based on the plot shown in the question.)

The charactersistic equation of the system is `-k (-(5/2)+s) (-2+s)+(-4+s) (-1+s)==0`.

- At `k==0` the roots are 1 and 4.
- As `k` increases the root at 1 moves to the left and the root at 4 moves to the right.
- At `k==1.02944` there is a double root at -6.24264. The root that started at 1 reaches there in a straightforward manner, but the root that started from 4 has to go all the way to infinity and back because of the discontinuity at `k==1`. On the plot the red loci starts at -4 goes all the way to infinity and then gets back to -6.24264. (With `ListPlot` I think we can see the entire real axis covered by red loci.) It also obscures the blue loci that started at 1 and reached -6.24264.
- From `k==1.02944` onwards there are two loci which start from -6.24264 and proceed in a manner symmetric about the real axis till they eventually wind up at the two zeros.

---

(Adding this based on comment below)

```
p1 = RootLocusPlot[
   TransferFunctionModel[-((k (s - 5/2) (s - 2)))/((s - 4) (s - 1)), 
    s], {k, 0, 0.99}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 15}, {-5, 5}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];

p2 = RootLocusPlot[
   TransferFunctionModel[-((k (s - 5/2) (s - 2)))/((s - 4) (s - 1)), 
    s], {k, 1.01, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 15}, {-5, 5}}, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}];

Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

(Update for v10)

In v10, the handling of loci which go to infinity and back has been improved. The default plot points still need to be tweaked to get `ParametricPlot` to give a smooth plot, but it is much cleaner that the earlier iteration.

```
RootLocusPlot[
TransferFunctionModel[-((k (s - 5/2) (s - 2)))/((s - 4) (s -    1)), 
s], {k, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 15}, {-5, 5}}, 
PlotPoints -> 90, MaxRecursion -> 10]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. What you wrote it is what I got by hand but I cannot see that on the result of RootLocusPlot. a) There is no blue loci coming from -infty (I have tried changing the range of k and etc but no show) and b) There seems to be a loci between pole at 1 and zero at 2, and between zero at 2.5 and pole at 4 (it should not be there). Another point: how to use ListPlot in this case?

Comment: a) RootLocusPlot[TransferFunctionModel[-((k (s - 5/2) (s - 2)))/((s - 4) (s - 1)), s], {k, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 15}, {-5, 5}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotPoints -> 300, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
 Method -> "GenericSolve"]

Comment: b) That is because the loci goes to infinity and come back. It is noise. We can split the process into two. I will post it along with the answer above. Regarding ListPlot, I did Table[Solve[-k (-(5/2)+s) (-2+s)+(-4+s) (-1+s)==0,s], {k, range of values}], obtained the real and imaginary parts and got a 'back of the envelope' kind of result with ListPlot.

Comment: Many thanks.  It worked but I am not happy with the noise (I used thickness[0.02] to see that the entire real axis is covered by the loci - that is not true unless we have negative gains - which we don't).  How to get rid of this noise? As for a) p2 gives me a distorted circle that does not seem right.

Comment: Just a comment - if you change the limit of k from 0.99 to 0.99999, and from 1.01 to 1.00001, the entire real axis is covered by the loci.

Comment: Actually, I do not see the entire real axis being covered. Even with values of 0.99999 and 1.00001 the loci does not between the poles at 1 and 4.

Comment: As for the distorted circle it is because of approximations. Increasing PoltPoints/MaxRecursion will give a smoother loci.

Comment: PlotPoints=7000 and MaxRecursion=15 (more than that, Mathematica sends a warning on my mac) are not enough to get rid of the distortion. The number of PlotPoints can be increased but the results take longer to show up.  As for the distortion, it seems that increasing the Maxrecursion does the job.  Many many thanks.